# Один родитель, множество элементов с одними значениями (сократить запись)

Tags: html, css

Есть универсальная запись формата

```
<div.class>
     <span>Lorem</span>
     <p>Lorem</p>
     <ul><li></li></ul>
</div>
```

Задача дать всем span, p, li и т. д. одни и те же стили
В стилях следующее:

```
 <style>  
  .class p{}
  .class span{}
  .class ul{}
  .class li{}
 </style>
```

Вопрос, как записать это максимально коротко и емко?

Comment: `span, p, li и т. д. {}`

Comment: @splash58, забыл `.class` перед каждым из

Comment: ну да :)  это точно

Comment: как раз и хотелось избежать очень длинного написания, * подошло идеально, пока обрабатываю

Comment: @VitaliyGusarov, обрати внимание что `*` применяется **ко всем** вложенным элементам, не обращая внимания на уровень вложенности

Comment: Это как раз таки и нужно, в действительности решает всю проблему!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам нужно использовать

```
.class * {

}
```

Comment: Я бы сказал что лучше использовать `.class>*`, малоли что будет внутри `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно работать с параметром **.class**.

Или вот так. Все характеристики применяться на все элементы **Div**.

```html
<div class="d">
     <span>Lorem</span>
     <p>Lorem</p>
     <ul><li>Lorem</li></ul>
</div>


<style>  
 .d span {
font-size: 60pt;
color: red;
  }
 .d p {
font-size: 40pt;
color: green;
  }
 .d li {
font-size: 20pt;
color: black;
  }
  
 </style>
```

Comment: вы не правы, не все css-свойства наследуются

Comment: Решение не плохое, но не все вложенности работают

Comment: Kirill это как раз то, что я имею, но у меня для всех элементов одни и те же стили, по этому я не хотел их дублировать, в scss проблемы не возникает, а в чистом css получается нагромождение.